# עוֹשֶׂה חֲדָשׁוֹת - what is this referring to?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, theology

In the morning *berachot* of Shema, we call Hashem **עוֹשֶׂה חֲדָשׁוֹת - Doer/Former of Novelties. What does this mean?** What is it referring to? [Possibly](https://www.sefaria.org/Reshit_Chokhmah%2C_Gate_of_Love.5.14?vhe=Hamesorah_Publishers,_Jerusalem_2005&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) referring to the "הַמְ**חַדֵּשׁ** בְּטוּבוֹ בְּכָל יוֹם תָּמִיד מַעֲשֵׂה בְרֵאשִׁית" - "Who, in His goodness, constantly renews the act of Bereshit every day" found afterwards in the [Sefardi version](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Weekday_Shacharit%2C_The_Shema.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?

Another question if possible on this: If there is [nothing new under the sun](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.1.9?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en), then how can He do new things under the sun? I would have less of a question if it said Creator/בורא of Novelties) as that would fit with what the Ramban [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.1.1.3), that when something is created from nothing, the hebrew word is בורא, whereas when something is formed from already-created stuff, that is עושה (interesting to note that the phrase is nothing new *under the sun*, but perhaps the sun itself - which is part of the theme of this *beracha* - can have חֲדָשׁוֹת?)

Comment: Hashem constantly needs to "create" the world; for if he were to stop creation would cease to exist.

Comment: @Shababnik I feel that what you said is very tangibly along the right lines +1. The issue I am having is that then it would make sense to say "creates novelties", according to the Ramban, and if it doesn't say that, then why, or what else is it referring to?

Comment: Kai. Perhaps according to the Rambam it's just a constant renewal as opposed to recreation

Comment: Maybe the Abudarham on there is interesting?

Comment: @Shababnik can the answer really be as simple as saying that He is recreating מַעֲשֵׂה_ בְרֵאשִׁית_, so it is a מַעֲשֵׂה that is being  מְחַדֵּשׁ?

Comment: @Shmuel assume you mean this? https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Weekday_Prayers%2C_Blessings_on_the_Shema.7?vhe=Abudarham._Lisbon,_1489.&lang=he&lookup=%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%97&with=Lexicon&lang2=he

Comment: @RabbiKaii Yep, did not have a good look at it, but I remember it.

Comment: @RabbiKaii not sure. These are just my thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rabbi Efrem Goldberg](https://rabbiefremgoldberg.org/rabbi-efrem-goldberg) has a great, ongoing series on the siddur. [Here](https://rabbiefremgoldberg.org/topics/category:6-minute-siddur-snippets) (you need to scroll down the list) in Episode 233 - Pesukei D’Zimra – Birchos Shema: L'Kayl Baruch (Part 3) he says the following:

When you look around the world you see leaders in innovation, novelty and discovery, but the truth is that only Hashem is the true "oseh chadashos" - i.e. it is a reminder that Hashem is the real innovator. Everything we discover, is revealing something that was always there. So when humans come to a medical or technological breakthrough we are revealing something that was there all along. Only Hashem can create something that is "Yeish MeiAyin" - ex nihilo.

Mankind is sometimes misguided. For example, we cobble together some ingredients and make the most spectacular culinary masterpiece, and we think we have created a game-changing gastronomic delicacy, but when we stop to think about it, we need to realise that Hashem was the one who created those ingredients in the first place. We merely put them together.

Anything true and new comes from G-d. This is something that Shlomo Hamelech explains in [Koheles 1:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.1.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> וְאֵ֥ין כָּל־חָדָ֖שׁ תַּ֥חַת הַשָּֽׁמֶשׁ
>
> There is nothing new under the sun.

In a similar vein, *[Rav Schwab on Prayer](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195121.html)* p. 281 writes as follows:

> **עוֹשֶׂה חֲדָשׁוֹת** - The malachim continue: **He alone is the Maker of new inventions.** Since the beginning of the world, man has continually developed his life with new inventions. Beginning with the very primitive Stone Age, graduating to the Bronze Age, and later to the Dark and Middle Ages, mankind has made constant innovations, which rendered the previous ones obsolete. Even the work of the great inventors of the recent past has been made obsolete in our modern computerized age. Who gave all these people the ideas and intelligence to make all these innovations? It is הוא לבדו, only Hakadosh Baruch Hu.

Comment: Rabbi Golberg can't fail to hit a home run in any answer he is quoted in! Very good thank you. To frame in terms of my question: the Yesh MeAyin is one thing, and all the different forms/עושה that He invested it with are the "חֲדָשׁוֹת", and the reason it is in our prayer is because we are meant to remember that, especially when we are tempted to think that חֲדָשׁוֹת are ours?

Comment: Correct - look at the Rav Schwab quote he says it better than I can...

Comment: A fine explanation, thanks for reminding me to learn more from these 2

Comment: Pleasure! :-) (15 char)